# Select multiple items in QListWidget programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

It's possible to select a single item/row, but I want to set multiple items selected (the widget is configured to allow that). Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find all QListWidgetItem* items you want to select and use QListWidgetItem::setSelected on them. This should support multiple selection if the list is configured for QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this question while looking for the same answer. However, I am using Python (PyQt5) with Qt Creator.

Using PyQt5 you can set the SelectionMode by using:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets    


QtWidgets.QListWidget.setSelectionMode(2)
```

where

- SelectionMode = 0 => NoSelection
- SelectionMode = 1 => SingleSelection
- SelectionMode = 2 => MultiSelection
- SelectionMode = 3 => ExtendedSelection
- SelectionMode = 4 => ContiguousSelection

[Reference](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum)

In Qt Creator you find this option here:
[image]